# Questions about the term 自殺志願者

Tags: words

My Japanese friend used the term 自殺志願者 jokingly in a journal entry, saying she sometimes wondered if she qualified for such a  position. I could not find a specific dictionary definition for this word, but found it translated as:

> suicide wanna-be
>
> those who want to kill oneself
>
> would-be suicide
>
> suicide volunteer/ suicide candidate (the latter being the most literal translation)

In common context is this word ironic? Is it a comedic term in and of itself? If it is a common word, is it used mostly in a clinical or in a jocular way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

自殺志願者 usually means its literal meaning: “a person who has a desire to commit suicide.”  Although anything can be used in an ironic way, I do not think that it is particularly common to use this word ironically.

I have seen the word 自殺志願者 or similar words in a derogatory sense, “a person who does such a stupid and dangerous thing that it cannot be explained unless he/she wants to kill him/herself.”

Comment: Ok thanks. I asked because most dictionaries listed 志願者 as "applicant; candidate" (i.e., those applying for school entry or a job). I also saw "volunteer" but in a less verifiable source. So I thought maybe someone "applying" for the opportunity to commit suicide would be somewhat ironic. But maybe I am reading too much into it?

Comment: @yadokari: Ah, I see.  志願する is indeed usually used for applying for school or job, but 自殺志願者 is a usual term to refer to a person who has a desire to commit suicide.  The “desire to commit suicide” itself is 自殺願望, and I do not know why a person who has such desire is usually called not 自殺願望者 but 自殺志願者.  (By the way, thanks for the edit!)

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for the further elucidation. That answers my questions.

Comment: Do you think 自殺志望者 is a more common term?

Comment: @yadokari: I do not know, but without checking anything, my guess is no.  This may be just me, but the word 自殺志望者 sounds a little funny to me because of a possible pun between 志望 and 死亡.  Because of this, I probably avoid using the word 自殺志望者 in any serious situation.